# c++builder style override options

Tags: styles, themes, c++builder, vcl

I'm having a problem with vcl styles overwriting custom colours. Is there a way to turn off styles when using onDrawItem, or detect when a style is on, and what the target colour will be?

Specifically, in this particular case, if the style is on the dark mode, text is made white, and in my case I need the background to be white. So white text against white background is invisible.

It looks like the pen color is being ignored and replaced with the style color, while background colors are correct.

Ideally, I'd like to ignore style stuff while in this particular draw routine, and just use my own colors. (Using C++Builder 11)

TIA

The code in question:

```
//TCheckListBox *clbxCategory;
void __fastcall TFormATB::clbxCategoryDrawItem(TWinControl* Control, 
                                               int Index, TRect &Rect, TOwnerDrawState State)
{
  if(State.Contains(odSelected))  {
    clbxCategory->Canvas->Pen->Color = clBlack;
    clbxCategory->Canvas->Brush->Color = clActiveCaption;
    clbxCategory->Canvas->RoundRect(Rect.Left, Rect.Top , Rect.Right, Rect.Bottom, 0, 50);
  }
  else  {
    clbxCategory->Canvas->Pen->Color = Colours[Index];
    clbxCategory->Canvas->Brush->Color = Colours[Index];
  }
  clbxCategory->Canvas->Rectangle(Rect.Left, Rect.Top - 1, Rect.Right, Rect.Bottom + 1);
  clbxCategory->Canvas->TextOut(Rect.Left, Rect.Top,clbxCategory->Items->Strings[Index]);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: You could do `auto ctl = static_cast<TCustomListBox*>(Control);` and use `ctl` in the function instead of `clbxCategory` to make it clear that it's a `TCustomListBox` decendant you are drawing in. At least, that's what I'm guessing. You could also simplify it and use `Rect` as-is in some cases: `clbxCategory->Canvas->RoundRect(Rect, 0, 50);` and also `clbxCategory->Canvas->Rectangle(Rect);`

Comment: Oh,  couldn't see a bit of difference between your original and with my simplifications. At least not for the `RoundRect` one. The other, where you `-1` and `+ 1`, not sure.

Comment: I added a comment to show that clbxCategory is a TChecklistBox. (Deleted my previous comment as it was garbage :) )